# Action on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, document-ready

I have beginner question about submit behavior. Every time I press submit my loginModal keep coming back up, is this expected behavior? Its like the ready() function is fired again. I would like my initiate App() function to be executed after submit

Here is bits of my code:

```
//Show loginModal on page ready
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');
    });

//loginModal submit
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>`enter code here`
</div>

//When submit button is clicked 
$('#loginModal').submit(function() {}
    initiateApp()

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default behviour of the submit button i.e. to refresh the page. Use `event.preventDefault()`

```
$('#loginModal').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        initiateApp()
    }

);
```

Comment: Sure glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you chose to use an input type of Submit, once you click the button it will trigger an auto post-back to my knowledge and refresh the page. Try using:

```
<button>

OR

<input type='button'>
```

This will stop the page from refreshing. Give it a shot!